# SharePoint fields missing

Tags: cognito-forms, sharepoint

I have a rather large form being sent to a SharePoint list.  I have recreated all of the fields as columns (single line of text) on the SharePoint list.  I copied/pasted the field names into column names.

When I submit a form, not all of the fields are being populated in the SharePoint list.  I went back and double checked to see if I had misspelled the names in SharePoint list but they are all correct.  I am stumped.

Any help?

https://www.cognitoforms.com/CityOfEauClaire/EauClairePDCitizenSelfReportForm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

In many cases, the “internal” column name in SharePoint does not match the Cognito Form field name. The "internal" column name in SharePoint is the initial name that is used when the column is created. For instance, if a SharePoint column is initially created with the name of “FirstName” but later renamed to “First Name”, the Cognito Form field of "First Name" would not successfully post to that field. A quick way to check the SharePoint internal column name would be to click a column from the list settings page and view the URL. The internal name will appear at the end of the URL:
https://{...}/Field=First%5Fx0020%5FName